# correct way to copy and paste

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making this code in excel that makes a copy of a certain range and then opens the other workbook and pastes this data in the correct range. Sometimes when I make some adjustments in the code, it does not work properly anymore. So I did some research and now I think I can make a little upgrade on my code, but I'm not certain how.

**Basics of my code** 
The code first searches for a range to copy, then the other workbook gets opened. In this workbook, a range to paste the data is found then the data which is copied will be pasted in that range. the workbooks get closed.

**This is what I found on google** 
I found this code on google (it is based on a different code) but maybe I can use this code to upgrade mine, so it will be more reliable.

```
Sheets("All_Rentals").Range("AA8") = .Range("B34").Value
```

I tried to use this code but without any good result, I tried something like this:

```
Rngp = rngc
```

But I don't think it works like this so what can I do then?

**This are parts of my code**

Code that copies a certain range:

```
Dim rngc As Range
Set rngc = 
Workbooks(ThisFile).Sheets("Planning").Range(Cells(11,Weekcolumn.Column), 
Cells(12, Weekcolumn.Offset(0, 106).Column))
rngc.copy
```

Code that finds the range to paste:

```
Dim CurrentBureauWeek As String
        CurrentBureauWeek = 
Workbooks(ThisFile).Sheets("Planning").Range("D3").Value

With Workbooks("Bureauplanning.xlsm").Sheets("Planning").Range("M10:DM10")
Set ThisWeek = .Find(What:=CurrentBureauWeek, LookIn:=xlValues, 
LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, Searchformat:=False)
If Not ThisWeek Is Nothing Then

End If
End With


Dim Thisprojecrow As Range

With Workbooks("Bureauplanning.xlsm").Sheets("Planning").Range("A:A")
Set Thisprojectrow = .Find(What:=Thisproject, LookIn:=xlValues, 
LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, Searchformat:=False)
If Not Thisprojectrow Is Nothing Then

End If
End With
```

Code that pastes the data:

```
Dim rngp As Range
Set rngp= Workbooks("Bureauplanning.xlsm"). 
Sheets("Planning").Cells(Thisprojectrow.Offse t(-2, 0).row, 
ThisWeek.Column)
rngp.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

I hope someone can help me to upgrade my code so it works better.

Comment: **Tip:** Do not copy till you have identified the range where you want to paste. Excel has an uncanny habit of clearing the clipboard. So the steps should be **1.** Identify the range to be copied. Store it in a range object **2.** Identify the range where the copied range needs to be pasted. Store it in a range object. **3.** Copy and immediatley paste. Avoid performing any other operation (except `DoEvents` if required) in between.

Comment: It's hard to tell from the code ,but most likely either the area being copied is not the same area as that being pasted, or as @SiddharthRout mentioned, the copied object is somehow cleared inbetween. Can you provide us with an Error Code? Does it get hung up on a particular line?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks for the tip, im gonna try to make that.

Comment: @rohrl77 I get this error code: excel vba error 1004 pastespecial method of range class failed. So maybe it's gone when I made my adjustments

Comment: @JellevanderHeijden in case you find the answer you are looking for vote it to help others with the same question.

Comment: @Error1004 yes, I found my answer. I like to thank all the replies from everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Rngp = rngc` should work, but omit `.Copy` as it is not necessary to use this function.

In the code you provided, you are copying and pasting values using `xlPasteValues`

A faster method is to set the values of range *A* to be equal to those of range *B*. In other words:

```
Range(DestinationRange).Value = Range(CopyRange).Value
```

This would paste the values from the range behind the `=` to the first range.

Note that, in order to copy all values, these ranges have to be equal in size.

**Therefore, for your code** (ranges as an example):

```
Dim rngc As Range
Dim rngp as Range
Dim sht As Sheet

Weekcolumn = 5
ThisFile = "Book1"

Set sht = Workbooks(ThisFile).Sheets("Planning")

With sht

Set rngc = .Range(.Cells(11, Weekcolumn.Column), .Cells(12, Weekcolumn.Offset(0, 106).Column))
Set rngp = .Range(.Cells(11,Weekcolumn.Column + 1), .Cells(12, Weekcolumn.Offset(0, 106).Column + 1))

rngp.Value = rngc.Value

End With
```

**EDIT for OP's comment**

```
Workbooks("Book2").Sheets(1).Range("L20:L30").Value = Workbooks("Book1").Sheets(1).Range("A1:A10").Value
```

Comment: Ah, thanks I did not know that the copy and paste range had to be the same size, is there a method the make a copied range past in a "start cell"? So I copy a range, for example, A1:A10, then I paste it in a different workbook in cell L20.

Comment: If you are using this method, the ranges have to be equal. For using `.Copy` you could define only the starter cell. Remember my explanation, this method is saying `Range(targetrange) = Range(copyrange)`. I have added your example to my answer

Comment: Right, I know its possible to use offsets in the code, can I also do that with this code?

Comment: Yes. All you are doing is defining two ranges. Does not matter how you do this, as long as they are both two valid ranges! Note that using `.Copy` is slower than this method.

Answer (score 0):

Some options are:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

    Set wb1 = Workbooks("Book1") '<- Make sure both workbooks are open
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("Book2")

    Set rng1 = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B2")
    Set rng2 = wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

    'Copy Contents and Formatting
    rng1.Copy rng2

    'Copy Contents
    rng1.Copy
    rng2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean whit the line: copy contents and formatting? (rng1.copy rng2) i dont understand what this does different then rng1.copy - rng2.pastspecual paste:=xlpastevalues?

Comment: By copying format we mean eg. Bold, Fill & Font Color etc

Comment: so I use that bit of code? and then use rng2.pastespecial?

Comment: no, if you want to copy both Contents and Formatting you write *rng1.Copy rng2*

Comment: oke, I may be misunderstanding it completely here but how do I paste that copied data?

Comment: rng1.Copy represent the range to be copy. rng2 represent the destination.